# How to enable Active Directory SSO/seamless-authentication on Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, active-directory

I work in a company where they use Active Directory. I am not in the IT and the IT do not have experience with Python. All the internal websites recognize the users by name, ID and job role automatically without the need to login again (single sign on). How can I enable this in Flask?

Comment: did you ever get this working?

Comment: I never experimented this. We are deploying a project now. Once done, I will feedback how we did it.